# AIML Interpreter Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, bots, aiml

I'm trying to write a AIML interpreter to develop AI bot. I went through several implementations of aiml interpreters but still I find it difficult to understand the algorithm behind it.

So if anyone can describe the general aiml interpreter algorithm or point out proper specification or document which I can used to understand it will be a great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

AIML interpreters uses **pattern matching** technique. It finds the best and longest pattern match of the keyword.

Basically, it will **search** through the categories of the whole knowledge base for values enclosed in `<pattern>` tag which matches the keyword.

Then, it will **return** the value enclosed within the `<template>` tag corresponding to the matching `<pattern>`.

There are also **priorities** for search areas. For example, if the chatbot conversations is within a certain `<topic>`, it will search for matches within the topic first. If match is not found, it will then search through the whole knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the newer Java AIML 2.0 interpreter Program AB at https://code.google.com/p/program-ab/